# splitting words for full name in only one variable

Tags: c++, string, iostream

I want to separate a full name from each other. It only works for first name.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     string FullName;
     int i = 0;
     cout <<"Enter your full name "<<endl;
     getline(cin,FullName);

     while (FullName[i] != ' ')
     {
         cout<<FullName.substr(i,FullName.find(' '))<<endl;;
         i++;
     }

     cout <<endl;
     }
return 0
}
```

I want to separate each name in a separate line like this: If I enter this:

```
     Max Michael Max
```

the output should be with each name in a separate new line:

```
     Max
     Michael
     Max
```

How can I split names each one in separate line ?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program one line at a time, and inspect the value of `i`, after executing each line of the program, what observations did you make?

Comment: I can't find a question here

Comment: i can't think about the algorithm for this problem for sorry

Comment: `FullName.substr(i,FullName.find(' '))` As described in the documentation of [`std::string::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr), the second argument is the length, of the substring, not an index, at which to stop generating the substring.

Comment: You can use [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) to split the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use `std::istringstream` after the name is read in.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     string FullName;
     cout <<"Enter your full name "<<endl;
     getline(cin, FullName);
     string namepart;
     istringstream strm(FullName);
     while ( strm >> namepart )
        cout << namepart << '\n';
}
```

[Live Example](https://www.ideone.com/M38q3V)